# Error '__init__ called too many times' while monkey patching

Tags: python, eventlet

I am using *eventlet* module. When I try to `monkey_patch` the code exits with *error*:

```
'__init__ called too many times'
```

Here's the code that's causing problem:

```
from eventlet import *
patcher.monkey_patch(all=True)

import os, glob, pandas, logging
import numpy as np
import boto3
import datetime
```

The `import` works fine, but `monkey` patching is the step where I see *error*.

EDIT:

Here's the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "check.py", line 4, in <module>
    import os, glob, pandas, logging
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pandas.core.internals import BlockManager
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.sparse.array import _maybe_to_sparse, SparseArray
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\sparse\array.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pandas.core.ops as ops
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 15, in <module>
    import pandas.computation.expressions as expressions
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\computation\expressions.py", line 15, in <module>
    import numexpr as ne
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numexpr\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from numexpr.expressions import E
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numexpr\expressions.py", line 81, in <module>
    _context = Context({})
  File "d:\Python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numexpr\expressions.py", line 67, in __init__
    raise SystemError('__init__ called too many times')
SystemError: __init__ called too many times
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: @AdamSmith added the stack trace

Comment: This code works for me with eventlet master (0.18), Python 3.4, OSX. What versions do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it without `all=True`:

```
patcher.monkey_patch()
```

(you basically have called a class several times)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Windows machines in particular.. patcher.monkey_patch() is working perfectly fine for me in OSX, while the same code returns with - 
SystemError: **init** called too many times for my colleagues using wondows machines ..

I am still searching for a solution for this issue.